# Validate that a dropdown is selected if another dropdown is selected

Tags: validation, knockout.js

I have two dropdowns on an form. If the user selects a value from the first dropdown, I want to make sure they make a choice from the second dropdown. I'm new to knockout, so I'm not sure how to do this. I don't think I need a fullblown validation library. I just want to stop the action so the popup doesn't go away and some text appears saying "hey you, pick something!"

The row looks like this:

```
<div class="channelRow" data-bind="foreach: channels">
    <div class="channelPrompt">CHANNEL: </div>
    <select class="channelSelect" name="channels" data-bind="options: $root.financialVM.channelOptions(), value: name, optionsCaption: '--'"></select>
    <div class="portPrompt">NUMBER OF PORTS: </div>
    <select class="portSelect" name="ports" data-bind="options: $root.financialVM.portOptions(), value: port, optionsCaption: '--'"></select>
</div>
```

Update:

Here's the function that I'm working with. Edge is a modal window that appears and is where the select boxes are.

```
function Edge (siteA, siteB, key, channelpair) {
    var edge = this;
    edge.siteA = ko.observable(siteA);
    edge.siteB = ko.observable(siteB);
    edge.distance = ko.observable(0);
    edge.key = ko.observable(key);
    edge.channels = ko.observableArray([
        new ChannelPair()
    ]);

    edge.addChannel = function () {
        if(edge.channels().length >= 3) return;
        edge.channels.push(new ChannelPair());
    };
}

function ChannelPair () {
    var channel = this;
    channel.name = ko.observable();
    channel.port = ko.observable(0);

    channel.port.extend({
        required: {
            message: "You can not have a name without a port",
            onlyIf: function () { return (self.name() != null); }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It would help if you prepare an example online. I created **[this codepen as a starting point](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CwgJI)**. If you could fit it to your requirements it is easier for others to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok here is a complete solution for you:

```
// You need this config in order to kick things off
ko.validation.configure({
    messagesOnModified: true,
    insertMessages: true
});

function Edge (siteA, siteB, key, channelpair) {
        var edge = this;
        edge.siteA = ko.observable(siteA);
        edge.siteB = ko.observable(siteB);
        edge.distance = ko.observable(0);
        edge.key = ko.observable(key);
        edge.channels = ko.observableArray([
            new ChannelPair()
        ]);

        edge.addChannel = function () {
            if(edge.channels().length >= 3) return;
            edge.channels.push(new ChannelPair());
        };
    }

    function ChannelPair () {
        var channel = this;
        channel.name = ko.observable();
            // Extending happens on declaration not after wards
        channel.port = ko.observable(0).extend({
            required: {
                message: "You can not have a name without a port",
                // self doesn't mean anything here so replace it with channel like this
                onlyIf: function () { return (channel.name() != null); }
            }
        });
        // you need a property called errors to keep your validation group in it
        channel.errors = ko.validation.group(channel);
    }
```

Also remember to add knockout validation to your project. Its a plugin and not shipped as  part of knockout out of the box.

Comment: You can use a computed instead of standard function too

Comment: I'm still not able to get it to validate. I added a code snippet her: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8242910

I tweaked your code just a bit so you can see what I'm doing. Edge is a modal window that appears where the select boxes are.

Comment: I wrote the complete solution for you now.

Comment: This is way better then the solution I ended up doing on Friday. I took the two drop downs values as a json object, looped it via .each, and then looked for undefined. If I hit a situation where one of the pair had a value and the other was undefined I threw an alert.

Thank you for your help, I appreciate it!

Comment: Im glad it helped but its not going to replace hiring a front end developer ;)